# How to load a pickle by pandas not from the file

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

since previously the code:

```
def read_pickle_packet(self, sf):
    body = self._read_payload(sf)

    return pickle.load(body)
```

has an error:ImportError: No module named indexes.base. which was caused by the pandas version inconsistent between server and client.
I solve the problem by changing the code like this:

```
def read_pickle_packet(self, sf):
    body = self._read_payload(sf)
    filehandler = open("tempFile.pkl", 'w')
    filehandler.write(body)
    filehandler.close()
    return pd.read_pickle("tempFile.pkl")
```

It can solve the problem.
But my question is there any more quick way to load the pickle object rather than store it into filesystem and then read it. It cost time and memory.But i could not found some clue by google "pandas read pickle from object".
Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code of the error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `pd.read_pickle` is only for reading from a file.
If you don't need to use the pandas library, you can skip saving to disk if you use `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).
I am not sure if this works in your case since I am not clear about your `_read_payload` function, though.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

x = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3], "y": [4,5,6]})
print(x)

obj = pickle.dumps(x)
z = pickle.loads(obj)
print(z)
```

Comment: The original code is written by using the pickle.loads(obj).But i have the error message because of the inconsistent pandas's version that my client version is 0.23 and the server part is 0.19.

Comment: I see.  Can you explain what `_read_payload` function does?  I am curious how this overcomes the challenge.

Comment: The _read_payload is to get the response via a connection. I think i can not change this function.

Comment: What are you passing as `sf`?  The result of `pickle.dumps`?  A reproducible data flow will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, actually it an sdk that i used, the `sf` should be the settings of the socket, so that i can get the server's `pickle.dumps` result.